Why Won't My Visualize_Transition Work Anymore?
I recently downgraded my qiskit from 1.1.1 to 0.46.2, and ever since then, my visualize_transition will not work. It worked perfectly before, and now it has a very long error message that I can't understand. I double-checked how I imported my libraries, too, and they should be correct... I really don't know what's going wrong. A picture of my code and the error message is attached.
Can someone please tell me the problem, and how to fix it?
Thanks so much!!


It looks a version of matplotlib is invalid. what's its version?  import matplotlib
matplotlib.version

As visualize_transition expects that matplotlib's version consists of integer number such as "3.8.3", it will give an error if its version includes a non-integer such as "post1". Upgrading to its version which consists of all integer only will solve the error.
if tuple(int(x) for x in matplotlib.__version__.split(".")) >= (3, 4, 0):

I assume you're currently using matplotlib==3.9.1.post1. So, just follow this :
On your terminal,

%pip uninstall matplotlib
%pip install matplotlib==3.9.0

matplotlib ver 3.9.0 should work.


What version should I update to?

I've added a comment at the end of my answer.

Thank you so much!
